# How to search a value in C# Hashtable based on current value and get the key rather than TRUE or FALSE

Tags: c#, hashtable

I was trying to solve a question that says, Check if the SUM any two element values from a given int[] is equal to a given sum value, return true and nothing found after checking all elements, return false.

I solved this using nested for..loop easily as below:

```
public bool CheckValue (int[] given, int sum) {
    if (given == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (given.Length == 0 || given.Length == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < given.Length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < given.Length; j++) {
                if ((given[i] + given[j]) == sum) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

But I wanted to solve it using Hashtable for the second loop because it will simplify the search process and tried the below code:

```
private static bool CheckValueUsingHashTable (int[] given, int sum) {
    if (given == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (given.Length == 0 || given.Length == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Hashtable hashs = new Hashtable ();

        for (int i = 0; i < given.Length; i++) {
            hashs.Add (i, given[i]);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < given.Length; j++) {
            int valueToAdd = sum - given[j];
            if (hashs.ContainsValue (valueToAdd)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem I face now is if the given array is {1,2,3,4} and the given sum is 2, it can add the first element with itself and returns TRUE but obviously, I don't want that to happen.

So, please how can I search a value from a Hashtable and get the key. Currently the function returns TRUE or FALSE based on the values existence.

Comment: *"if the given array is {1,2,3,4} and the given sum is 2, it can add the first element with itself and returns TRUE but obviuosly, i dont want that to happen"* -- however obvious that may be, what's not obvious is what you *do* want to happen instead. What do you want ot return in that case? `False`? `2`? `new Object()`? Please be clear.

Comment: You already know what the key is (it's in `valueToAdd`). I think the solution for you is to check if `valueToAdd` and `given[j]` are equal.

Comment: Note that `HashTable.ContainsValue` is O(n), not O(1). You're not gaining anything by using `HashTable.ContainsValue` (and paying quite a lot of overhead, with boxing each `int` and `HashTable` having to call its virtual `Equals` method instead of just doing a direct equality check)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after? Assuming that `given` can't contain the same number twice.

```
public static bool CheckValue(int[] given, int sum)
{
    if (given == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (given.Length == 0 || given.Length == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(given);

    foreach (int num in given)
    {
        int remainder = sum - num;
        if (remainder != num && hashSet.Contains(remainder))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

We use a `HashSet<int>`, which is effectively a HashSet/Dictionary which only contains keys. For each possible number, we find the remainder. We check that `remainder != num` (which gets around the problem of e.g. `sum` being `4`, `num` being 2, and us finding that `2` exists in `hashSet`), then see whether the remainder is in our HashSet.

You can add another optimization, provided that `given` is sorted:

```
foreach (int num in given)
{
    int remainder = sum - num;
    if (remainder != num && hashSet.Contains(remainder))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Addition is commutative (1 + 2 == 2 + 1), so if we're past the half-way point,
    // we're not going to find anything
    if (num > sum/2)
    {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

---

However, unless `given` is very large, this will almost certainly be *slower* than the naive solution in your question. Comparing ints directly is very quick, and `HashSet<T>`, although O(n), will add overheads.